# Scroll windows for code in iPython (Jupyter) Notebooks?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to display large blocks of code in an iPython notebook in a scroll window?

I have a notebook where the focus is on graphical output of the code and comments in the markdown text. I want to be able to execute the code in the notebook and have it available to the reader, but many of the code blocks are very lengthy. A scroll window would make a notebook much cleaner and more concise, allowing readers the option of moving past large code blocks.

Comment: Neither is exactly what you ask for, but you might be interested in the [Codefolding](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/Codefolding) and [Hide Input All](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/Hide-Input-All) extensions.

Comment: Excellent suggestions. Thanks. I particularly like the firstline comment folding.

Answer (score 1):

The best way so far is to use the `hide_code` package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hide_code/0.1.5). To install:

```
$ pip install hide_code
```

This will enable you to hide or display the content of each individual cell.
It is great !

Though I hope the vertical scroll bar for input cells will be available soon.