# Jupyter notebook make input cell scrollable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have input code cell in the notebook that contains a lot of lines of code. I can't split it into different cells so its a long line of code block.
I would like to make it scrollable so that its easier to navigate within the notebook. Is it possible to do in jupyter?

Again, I need the vertical scrolling for code block (INPUT cell) not output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter Notebook: enable vertical scrolling in code block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528650/jupyter-notebook-enable-vertical-scrolling-in-code-block)

Comment: Those are not duplicates. Please read the question and answers. They are asking for output cell but I need vertical scrolling for the `CODE` (INPUT) cell.

Comment: You are right. My bad, sorry.

Comment: I don't believe that there is an option to do this; at least [there wasn't as of Jun 8th 2017](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2558#issuecomment-307115709).