# Output scroll with Sphinx in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx

If I have a long output cell in a jupyter notebook, for example for the following code, [it's possible to activate the scroll on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37098584/4987722):

```py
for ii in range(40):
    print(f"this is output line {ii}")
```

I'm also rendering the notebook with Sphinx for a documentation, but it doesn't include the scroll bar for the output cell.

I tried to add the proposed ["scroll-output"](https://sphinx-book-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebooks.html#scrolling-cell-outputs) and ["output_scroll"](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/content/code-outputs.html#scrolling-cell-outputs) tags, but they have no effect.

Is there a way to fix this issue?